# Display one form and return text to another - Java

Tags: c#, java, events, swing, netbeans

I have an application in C# that I am converting to Java, specifically the C# version consists of a Windows Form (Main Form) that spawns a new form (Secondary Form) via the ShowDialog() method.

The event handler for a button (OK) on the Secondary form sets it's DialogResult to OK when clicked, therefore in the Main Form I can check what DialogResult was set and retrieve data from the Secondary Form instance through properties.

I'm using SwingUI with NetBeans and I was wondering how I would go about implementing the same functionality in the Java application.

An example:

**The Box to be displayed (Secondary Form):**

[image]

**The behaviour for the Secondary Form:**

[image]

**Then a simple piece of code in the Main Form to get the results:**

[image]

As you can see it doesn't really take a lot of effort to achieve this in C#, how big of a task would it be to do it in Java?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dialog that returns a String:

```
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                frame,
                "Complete the sentence:\n"
                + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                "Customized Dialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                icon,
                possibilities,
                "ham");
```

Taken from the [Swing Dialog tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).  You can create a more complex dialog by subclassing the [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) class and creating accessor methods to get the data.

Comment: Another approach it to provide a `JPanel` containing the editing controls to `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`.  If the result is `OK_OPTION`, update the main fields from the ones included in the edit panel.